# Build Issue from docker file Nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

I had created my Dockerfile, and in my docker file when I am trying to build and run But it gives me an error that the expression is not found. What is the issue? Can anyone help me resolve this issue or guide me?

```
> payment-gateway-react@0.1.0 start
> NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/server/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server/index.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
  (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/server/index.js' ]
```

My Dockerfile is

```sh
# Stage 1: Build environment

FROM node:16.19.0-alpine AS build
LABEL pgseamlessappversion="1.0.0.0" \
      contact="Vouchagram" \
      description="A minimal React.js Docker image for PGSeamless application" \
      base.image="Node" \
      maintainer="raj.r@gyftr.com"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json

COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies

RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application

COPY . /usr/src/app/.

# Build the Next.js application

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Production environment with Alpine
FROM node:16.19.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy only the necessary files from the build stage

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/public ./public

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/server./server

# Expose the necessary port
EXPOSE 6540

# Start the Next.js application
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: You haven't copied your `node_modules` tree into the final image.  (Do you need to `RUN NODE_ENV=production npm ci` instead, to avoid the development-only dependencies?)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of `Next.js` you are using.

### For Next.js v12 or below:

You need to copy the `node_modules` in your **Copy only the necessary files from the build stage** step

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
```

On a side note, this contains both `dependencies` as well as `devDependencies`. Hence, you can reduce your docker image size by not having `devDependencies` in your final image.

So rather than copy the whole `node_modules` directory, you can install the `dependencies` alone by:

```
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/server./server

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN npm ci
```

---

Also, I would recommend you to use `npm ci` over `npm install`, because the latter might not be installing the same version of the packages defined in `package.json`.

> *npm ci*
>
> This command is similar to npm install, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies.
>
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci